# Count rows from query laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

[Web View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfAuM.png)

I am trying to count the total for each medication listed and break it down by the total of each medication and then total by location. All of this data is in one table. The controller I am using to get each medication is below. I am trying to determine if I have to write a query for each tally I am looking for, or do I need to do a php count function for each, or does laravel have something to make this less time consuming?

```
enter code here public function index()
{
    $medications = ControlledSubstances::with('Medications', 'Locations')->paginate('10');

    $rx = Medications::where('controlled', '1')->get()
                ->keyBy('id')
                ->map(function ($rx){
                    return"{$rx->trade_name}  -  {$rx->brand_name}";
                });

    $cs = Medications::get();

    $nb = NarcoticBoxes::get()
                ->keyBy('id')
                ->map(function ($nb){
                    return"{$nb->box_number}";
                });

    $status = VialStatus::get()
                ->keyBy('id')
                ->map(function ($status){
                    return"{$status->label}";
                });

    return view('logistics.controlled', compact('medications', 'rx', 'nb', 'status', 'cs'))->with('success', 'New Controlled Substance Added');
}
```

Comment: does `count($returned)` not work? are you able to somehow add `count(*) as total` into the query and then $return['total'] will have your total?

Comment: I believe I could definately do the count(*) as total. Then would I have to write a new query for each of the statuses

Comment: so try `$count = count($result);` on the result. I'd be surprised if it's not returned in an array or `countable` object.

Comment: The result is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mcount = ControlledSubstances::
            select('medication', DB::raw('count(*) as count'), DB::raw('count(IF(status = 3,1,NULL)) safe'), DB::raw('count(IF(status = 4,1,NULL)) box'), DB::raw('count(IF(status = 8,1,NULL)) destroyed') ) 
            ->groupBy('medication')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [Laravel 5 Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries):

```
$price = DB::table('orders')
    ->where('finalized', 1)
    ->avg('price');
```

Then change `avg('price')` to `count()` will give you the count.

Alternatively:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
    ->where('status', '<>', 1)
    ->groupBy('status')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Still returns a count for just the query leaving me to write 16 queries to achieve what I was looking for. I am looking to count how many with a value of 1 in a column then a count for each status. Then the same for value 2 and so on. So the table holds medications. I want to count how many of each med carried is each status so I want to know that this medication we have 10 total and 2 are in boxes 6 are in the safe 4 are destroyed.

Comment: You may be able to try a subquery but that could still be rather long and not sure how that works with laravel models.